# How to check if predicate is true in c++?

Tags: c++, list, predicate

I get what they are supposed to do, but I don't know how to check if, for example, int data fulfils Pred pred when they are given to a function.
For example, I have this function in a singly linked list:
`Node<T>* extract(Node<T>*& head, Pred pred)`
with these values to check head->data:
`extract(listAi,[](int n) {return n % 2 == 0; });`

Comment: What is `extract` supposed to actually *do* ? Return a list containing *copies* of all the nodes answering true to the predicate? Or actually *remove* the nodes matching the predicate and return the removed nodes from the list? It makes a difference. Regardless, somewhere in your node type is a value member. That value is passed to the predicate, and the action taken thereafter depends on the result return from said-same.

Comment: @WhozCraig The function should
extract, to a separate list, all nodes for which predicate applied
to the member data returns true. The function extract returns the head
of the list containing nodes for which the predicate yields true, and, after returning
from extract, head points to the  list of nodes not
satisfying the predicate. So it should be like: pred(data)?

Comment: Again, the argument to the pred object will be the significant data *member* within `Node<T>`. E.g. the current node in the list enumeration being performed within extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the argument to the `pred` object will be the significant data member within `Node<T>`. E.g. the current node in the list enumeration being performed within extract.

Foregoing the ill-advised manual memory management (all of this is academic, since in the real world you'd use proper C++ containers and algorithms)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
struct Node
{
    T value;
    Node *next;

    Node(T obj)  
        : value(std::move(obj))
        , next(nullptr)
     {
     }
};

template<class T, class Pred>
Node<T> *extract(Node<T>*& head, Pred&& pred)
{
    Node<T> *result = nullptr;
    Node<T> **ppSrc = &head;
    Node<T> **ppDst = &result;

    while (*ppSrc)
    {
        if (pred((*ppSrc)->value)) // HERE: note value from node passed
        {
            *ppDst = *ppSrc;
            ppDst = &(*ppDst)->next;
            *ppSrc = (*ppSrc)->next;
        }
        else
        {
            ppSrc = &(*ppSrc)->next;
        }
    }

    // terminate the extracted list
    *ppDst = nullptr;

    return result;
} 

template<class T>
void printList(Node<T> const* head)
{
    if (head)
    {
        while (head)
        {
            std::cout << head->value << ' ';
            head = head->next;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node<int> *lst = nullptr;
    Node<int> **pp = &lst;
    for (int i=1; i<10; ++i)
    {
        *pp = new Node<int>(i);
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    *pp = nullptr;

    printList(lst);

    Node<int> *odds = extract(lst, [](int value) { return value % 2;});
    printList(odds);
    printList(lst);

    while (lst)
    {
        auto tmp = lst;
        lst = lst->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    while (odds)
    {
        auto tmp = odds;
        odds = odds->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9 
2 4 6 8
```